# XGBoost Feature Importance Showing Weight Instead of Gain?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I'm doing an XGBoost for a linear regression problem and the model works fine but is not printing out the feature importance (gain).

The results look like this:

[image]

But was expecting something like this:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and your complete code?

Answer (score 2):

The gain, cover, and frequency metrics are only for the `gbtree` booster.  The `gblinear` booster only gives weight.  Perhaps you would prefer to fit the gbtree booster?  That's the default option, and I think, what is most often used.

```r
library(xgboost)

m1 <- xgboost(
  data  = as.matrix(mtcars[, -1]),
  label = mtcars[, 1],
  nrounds = 50,
  verbose = 0
)

xgb.importance(model = m1)
#>     Feature         Gain       Cover   Frequency
#>  1:     cyl 4.387140e-01 0.020018810 0.039711191
#>  2:      wt 3.033430e-01 0.112723364 0.133574007
#>  3:    disp 1.870484e-01 0.391643155 0.332129964
#>  4:      hp 4.358684e-02 0.112051592 0.126353791
#>  5:    qsec 1.397432e-02 0.192798603 0.211191336
#>  6:    drat 1.082512e-02 0.090420529 0.106498195
#>  7:    carb 2.487836e-03 0.035469569 0.019855596
#>  8:    gear 1.177536e-05 0.015047696 0.009025271
#>  9:      vs 7.260741e-06 0.025392987 0.016245487
#> 10:      am 1.413125e-06 0.004433696 0.005415162

m2 <- xgboost(
  data  = as.matrix(mtcars[, -1]),
  label = mtcars[, 1],
  nrounds = 50,
  verbose = 0,
  booster = "gblinear"
)

xgb.importance(model = m2)
#>     Feature       Weight
#>  1:      am  3.411794186
#>  2:      vs  1.866894841
#>  3:    gear  1.492013931
#>  4:    carb -1.169109583
#>  5:    drat  0.893951356
#>  6:      wt -0.591026664
#>  7:     cyl  0.216187149
#>  8:    qsec  0.150260374
#>  9:      hp -0.014555559
#> 10:    disp -0.004487043
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>